# How do I solve the 'makefile std error undefined reference' error?

Tags: c++, makefile

I am completely new to C++, working on Linux or compiling in general. I have a code done by another fellow scientist and I am trying to compile and link his work using his own Makefile. Nevertheless, I get an error regarding undefined references...

The Makefile is

```
#CC = g++
CC = mpicxx
#CPPFLAGS = -I ../../include -g
#LDFLAGS =  -lboost_program_options -g
CPPFLAGS = -I ../../include -O3
LDFLAGS =  -lboost_program_options -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization -O3
BUILD = ../../build/
vpath %.h ../../include
#vpath %.cpp src

TARGET = calc_num_walks

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): calc_num_walks.o $(BUILD)origami_system.o $(BUILD)utility.o $(BUILD)nearest_neighbour.o $(BUILD)files.o $(BUILD)jsoncpp.o $(BUILD)domain.o $(BUILD)simulation.o $(BUILD)parser.o $(BUILD)random_gens.o $(BUILD)movetypes.o $(BUILD)ideal_random_walk.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

calc_num_walks.o: calc_num_walks.cpp
    $(CC) -c $^ $(CPPFLAGS)

clean:
    rm *.o
```

Now this is the output I receive after running the Makefile:

```
mpicxx -o calc_num_walks calc_num_walks.o ../../build/origami_system.o ../../build/utility.o ../../build/nearest_neighbour.o ../../build/files.o ../../build/jsoncpp.o ../../build/domain.o ../../build/simulation.o ../../build/parser.o ../../build/random_gens.o ../../build/movetypes.o ../../build/ideal_random_walk.o -lboost_program_options -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization -O3
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: calc_num_walks.o: in function `boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<boost::archive::binary_oarchive>::vsave(boost::archive::class_name_type const&)':
calc_num_walks.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7archive6detail15common_oarchiveINS0_15binary_oarchiveEE5vsaveERKNS0_15class_name_typeE[_ZN5boost7archive6detail15common_oarchiveINS0_15binary_oarchiveEE5vsaveERKNS0_15class_name_typeE]+0x43): undefined reference to `boost::archive::basic_binary_oprimitive<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::save(std::string const&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/origami_system.o: in function `origami::OrigamiSystem::OrigamiSystem(std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > const&, std::vector<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > const&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::vector<origami::Chain, std::allocator<origami::Chain> > const&, bool, double, parser::InputParameters&)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:63: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::OrigamiPotential(std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, std::vector<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > const&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, parser::InputParameters&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:63: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::~OrigamiPotential()'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/origami_system.o: in function `origami::OrigamiSystem::~OrigamiSystem()':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:74: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::~OrigamiPotential()'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/origami_system.o: in function `origami::OrigamiSystem::check_domains_complementary(domainContainer::Domain&, domainContainer::Domain&)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:136: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::check_domains_complementary(domainContainer::Domain&, domainContainer::Domain&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/origami_system.o: in function `origami::OrigamiSystem::update_enthalpy_and_entropy()':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:218: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::hybridization_enthalpy(domainContainer::Domain const&, domainContainer::Domain const&) const'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:220: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::hybridization_entropy(domainContainer::Domain const&, domainContainer::Domain const&) const'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:242: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::init_enthalpy() const'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:243: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::init_entropy() const'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/origami_system.o: in function `origami::OrigamiSystem::init_energy()':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:265: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::init_energy() const'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/origami_system.o: in function `origami::OrigamiSystem::check_all_constraints()':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:293: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::init_energy() const'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:324: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::init_energy() const'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/origami_system.o: in function `origami::OrigamiSystem::add_chain(int)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:397: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::init_energy() const'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/origami_system.o: in function `origami::OrigamiSystem::delete_chain(int)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:471: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::init_energy() const'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/origami_system.o: in function `origami::OrigamiSystem::set_checked_domain_config(domainContainer::Domain&, utility::VectorThree, utility::VectorThree)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:490: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::hybridization_energy(domainContainer::Domain const&, domainContainer::Domain const&) const'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:493: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::hybridization_energy(domainContainer::Domain const&, domainContainer::Domain const&) const'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:495: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::check_stacking(domainContainer::Domain&, domainContainer::Domain&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/origami_system.o: in function `origami::OrigamiSystem::update_temp(double, double)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:620: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::update_temp(double, double)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/origami_system.o: in function `origami::OrigamiSystem::initialize_staples(std::vector<origami::Chain, std::allocator<origami::Chain> >)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:673: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::init_energy() const'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/origami_system.o: in function `origami::OrigamiSystem::internal_unassign_domain(domainContainer::Domain&)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:704: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::check_stacking(domainContainer::Domain&, domainContainer::Domain&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/origami_system.o: in function `origami::OrigamiSystem::unassign_bound_domain(domainContainer::Domain&)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:743: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::hybridization_energy(domainContainer::Domain const&, domainContainer::Domain const&) const'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/origami_system.o: in function `origami::OrigamiSystem::update_energy()':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:824: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::init_energy() const'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/origami_system.o: in function `origami::OrigamiSystem::internal_check_domain_constraints(domainContainer::Domain&, utility::VectorThree, utility::VectorThree)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:850: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::bind_domain(domainContainer::Domain&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/origami_system.o: in function `origami::OrigamiSystemWithBias::check_domain_constraints(domainContainer::Domain&, utility::VectorThree, utility::VectorThree)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:907: undefined reference to `potential::OrigamiPotential::check_domains_complementary(domainContainer::Domain&, domainContainer::Domain&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:918: undefined reference to `orderParams::SystemOrderParams::check_one_domain(domainContainer::Domain&, utility::VectorThree, utility::VectorThree, utility::Occupancy)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:919: undefined reference to `biasFunctions::SystemBiases::check_one_domain(domainContainer::Domain&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/origami_system.o: in function `origami::OrigamiSystemWithBias::unassign_domain(domainContainer::Domain&)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:931: undefined reference to `orderParams::SystemOrderParams::update_one_domain(domainContainer::Domain&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:932: undefined reference to `biasFunctions::SystemBiases::calc_one_domain(domainContainer::Domain&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/origami_system.o: in function `origami::OrigamiSystemWithBias::set_checked_domain_config(domainContainer::Domain&, utility::VectorThree, utility::VectorThree)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:944: undefined reference to `orderParams::SystemOrderParams::update_one_domain(domainContainer::Domain&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:945: undefined reference to `biasFunctions::SystemBiases::calc_one_domain(domainContainer::Domain&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/origami_system.o: in function `origami::OrigamiSystemWithBias::set_domain_config(domainContainer::Domain&, utility::VectorThree, utility::VectorThree)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/origami_system.cpp:955: undefined reference to `biasFunctions::SystemBiases::calc_one_domain(domainContainer::Domain&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/origami_system.o: in function `std::_MakeUniq<orderParams::SystemOrderParams>::__single_object std::make_unique<orderParams::SystemOrderParams, parser::InputParameters&, origami::OrigamiSystem&>(parser::InputParameters&, origami::OrigamiSystem&)':
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:795: undefined reference to `orderParams::SystemOrderParams::SystemOrderParams(parser::InputParameters&, origami::OrigamiSystem&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/origami_system.o: in function `std::_MakeUniq<biasFunctions::SystemBiases>::__single_object std::make_unique<biasFunctions::SystemBiases, origami::OrigamiSystem&, orderParams::SystemOrderParams&, parser::InputParameters&>(origami::OrigamiSystem&, orderParams::SystemOrderParams&, parser::InputParameters&)':
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:795: undefined reference to `biasFunctions::SystemBiases::SystemBiases(origami::OrigamiSystem&, orderParams::SystemOrderParams&, parser::InputParameters&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/files.o: in function `files::OrigamiEnergiesOutputFile::write(long, double)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/files.cpp:652: undefined reference to `biasFunctions::SystemBiases::get_total_bias()'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/files.o: in function `files::OrigamiOrderParamsOutputFile::OrigamiOrderParamsOutputFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, int, int, origami::OrigamiSystem&, orderParams::SystemOrderParams&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/files.cpp:695: undefined reference to `orderParams::SystemOrderParams::get_order_param(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/simulation.o: in function `simulation::GCMCSimulation::setup_orientation_movetype(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, files::OrigamiMovetypeFile&, movetypes::MCMovetype*)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/simulation.cpp:305: undefined reference to `movetypes::OrientationRotationMCMovetype::OrientationRotationMCMovetype(origami::OrigamiSystem&, randomGen::RandomGens&, idealRandomWalk::IdealRandomWalks&, std::vector<files::OrigamiOutputFile*, std::allocator<files::OrigamiOutputFile*> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, orderParams::SystemOrderParams&, biasFunctions::SystemBiases&, parser::InputParameters&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/simulation.o: in function `simulation::GCMCSimulation::setup_staple_exchange_movetype(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, files::OrigamiMovetypeFile&, movetypes::MCMovetype*)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/simulation.cpp:331: undefined reference to `movetypes::MetStapleExchangeMCMovetype::MetStapleExchangeMCMovetype(origami::OrigamiSystem&, randomGen::RandomGens&, idealRandomWalk::IdealRandomWalks&, std::vector<files::OrigamiOutputFile*, std::allocator<files::OrigamiOutputFile*> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, orderParams::SystemOrderParams&, biasFunctions::SystemBiases&, parser::InputParameters&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, bool)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/simulation.o: in function `simulation::GCMCSimulation::setup_staple_regrowth_movetype(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, files::OrigamiMovetypeFile&, movetypes::MCMovetype*)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/simulation.cpp:352: undefined reference to `movetypes::MetStapleRegrowthMCMovetype::MetStapleRegrowthMCMovetype(origami::OrigamiSystem&, randomGen::RandomGens&, idealRandomWalk::IdealRandomWalks&, std::vector<files::OrigamiOutputFile*, std::allocator<files::OrigamiOutputFile*> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, orderParams::SystemOrderParams&, biasFunctions::SystemBiases&, parser::InputParameters&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/simulation.cpp:363: undefined reference to `movetypes::CBStapleRegrowthMCMovetype::CBStapleRegrowthMCMovetype(origami::OrigamiSystem&, randomGen::RandomGens&, idealRandomWalk::IdealRandomWalks&, std::vector<files::OrigamiOutputFile*, std::allocator<files::OrigamiOutputFile*> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, orderParams::SystemOrderParams&, biasFunctions::SystemBiases&, parser::InputParameters&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/simulation.o: in function `simulation::GCMCSimulation::setup_scaffold_regrowth_movetype(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, files::OrigamiMovetypeFile&, movetypes::MCMovetype*)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/simulation.cpp:391: undefined reference to `movetypes::CTCBScaffoldRegrowthMCMovetype::CTCBScaffoldRegrowthMCMovetype(origami::OrigamiSystem&, randomGen::RandomGens&, idealRandomWalk::IdealRandomWalks&, std::vector<files::OrigamiOutputFile*, std::allocator<files::OrigamiOutputFile*> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, orderParams::SystemOrderParams&, biasFunctions::SystemBiases&, parser::InputParameters&, int, int)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/simulation.cpp:407: undefined reference to `movetypes::CTCBJumpScaffoldRegrowthMCMovetype::CTCBJumpScaffoldRegrowthMCMovetype(origami::OrigamiSystem&, randomGen::RandomGens&, idealRandomWalk::IdealRandomWalks&, std::vector<files::OrigamiOutputFile*, std::allocator<files::OrigamiOutputFile*> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, orderParams::SystemOrderParams&, biasFunctions::SystemBiases&, parser::InputParameters&, int, int, int)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/simulation.o: in function `simulation::GCMCSimulation::setup_scaffold_transform_movetype(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, files::OrigamiMovetypeFile&, movetypes::MCMovetype*)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/simulation.cpp:442: undefined reference to `movetypes::CTCBLinkerRegrowthMCMovetype::CTCBLinkerRegrowthMCMovetype(origami::OrigamiSystem&, randomGen::RandomGens&, idealRandomWalk::IdealRandomWalks&, std::vector<files::OrigamiOutputFile*, std::allocator<files::OrigamiOutputFile*> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, orderParams::SystemOrderParams&, biasFunctions::SystemBiases&, parser::InputParameters&, int, int, int, unsigned int, unsigned int, int)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/simulation.cpp:458: undefined reference to `movetypes::CTCBClusteredLinkerRegrowthMCMovetype::CTCBClusteredLinkerRegrowthMCMovetype(origami::OrigamiSystem&, randomGen::RandomGens&, idealRandomWalk::IdealRandomWalks&, std::vector<files::OrigamiOutputFile*, std::allocator<files::OrigamiOutputFile*> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, orderParams::SystemOrderParams&, biasFunctions::SystemBiases&, parser::InputParameters&, int, int, int, unsigned int, int)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/simulation.cpp:480: undefined reference to `movetypes::CTRGLinkerRegrowthMCMovetype::CTRGLinkerRegrowthMCMovetype(origami::OrigamiSystem&, randomGen::RandomGens&, idealRandomWalk::IdealRandomWalks&, std::vector<files::OrigamiOutputFile*, std::allocator<files::OrigamiOutputFile*> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, orderParams::SystemOrderParams&, biasFunctions::SystemBiases&, parser::InputParameters&, int, int, int, int, int, unsigned int, unsigned int, int)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/simulation.o: in function `simulation::GCMCSimulation::setup_rg_movetype(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, files::OrigamiMovetypeFile&, movetypes::MCMovetype*)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/simulation.cpp:512: undefined reference to `movetypes::CTRGScaffoldRegrowthMCMovetype::CTRGScaffoldRegrowthMCMovetype(origami::OrigamiSystem&, randomGen::RandomGens&, idealRandomWalk::IdealRandomWalks&, std::vector<files::OrigamiOutputFile*, std::allocator<files::OrigamiOutputFile*> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, orderParams::SystemOrderParams&, biasFunctions::SystemBiases&, parser::InputParameters&, int, int, int, int)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/simulation.cpp:530: undefined reference to `movetypes::CTRGJumpScaffoldRegrowthMCMovetype::CTRGJumpScaffoldRegrowthMCMovetype(origami::OrigamiSystem&, randomGen::RandomGens&, idealRandomWalk::IdealRandomWalks&, std::vector<files::OrigamiOutputFile*, std::allocator<files::OrigamiOutputFile*> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, orderParams::SystemOrderParams&, biasFunctions::SystemBiases&, parser::InputParameters&, int, int, int, int, int)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/simulation.o: in function `simulation::GCMCSimulation::simulate(long long, long long, bool, std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/simulation.cpp:553: undefined reference to `orderParams::SystemOrderParams::update_move_params()'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/simulation.cpp:554: undefined reference to `biasFunctions::SystemBiases::calc_move()'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/simulation.o: in function `simulation::GCMCSimulation::write_log_entry(long long, bool, movetypes::MCMovetype&)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/simulation.cpp:657: undefined reference to `biasFunctions::SystemBiases::get_total_bias()'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/simulation.cpp:660: undefined reference to `biasFunctions::SystemBiases::get_domain_update_bias()'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/simulation.cpp:662: undefined reference to `biasFunctions::SystemBiases::get_move_update_bias()'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/simulation.o: in function `boost::system::error_code::error_code()':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:461: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/simulation.o: in function `boost::system::error_category::std_category::equivalent(int, std::error_condition const&) const':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:703: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:706: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/simulation.o: in function `boost::system::error_category::std_category::equivalent(std::error_code const&, int) const':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:733: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:736: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:748: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/simulation.o: in function `boost::filesystem::operator/(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&)':
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:792: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(boost::filesystem::path const&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/simulation.o: in function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
/usr/include/boost/asio/error.hpp:230: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/simulation.o: in function `boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code&)':
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:459: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/simulation.o: in function `std::hash<std::pair<utility::VectorThree, int> >::operator()(std::pair<utility::VectorThree, int> const&) const':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/include/hash.h:90: undefined reference to `std::hash_value(utility::VectorThree const&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/movetypes.o: in function `movetypes::CTRegrowthMCMovetype::CTRegrowthMCMovetype(origami::OrigamiSystem&, randomGen::RandomGens&, idealRandomWalk::IdealRandomWalks&, std::vector<files::OrigamiOutputFile*, std::allocator<files::OrigamiOutputFile*> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, orderParams::SystemOrderParams&, biasFunctions::SystemBiases&, parser::InputParameters&, int, int, int)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/movetypes.cpp:441: undefined reference to `topConstraintPoints::Constraintpoints::Constraintpoints(origami::OrigamiSystem&, idealRandomWalk::IdealRandomWalks&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/movetypes.o: in function `movetypes::CTRegrowthMCMovetype::CTRegrowthMCMovetype(origami::OrigamiSystem&, randomGen::RandomGens&, idealRandomWalk::IdealRandomWalks&, std::vector<files::OrigamiOutputFile*, std::allocator<files::OrigamiOutputFile*> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, orderParams::SystemOrderParams&, biasFunctions::SystemBiases&, parser::InputParameters&, int, int, int)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/movetypes.cpp:441: undefined reference to `topConstraintPoints::Constraintpoints::Constraintpoints(origami::OrigamiSystem&, idealRandomWalk::IdealRandomWalks&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/movetypes.o: in function `movetypes::CTRegrowthMCMovetype::reset_internal()':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/movetypes.cpp:447: undefined reference to `topConstraintPoints::Constraintpoints::reset_internal()'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/movetypes.o: in function `movetypes::CTRegrowthMCMovetype::select_indices(std::vector<domainContainer::Domain*, std::allocator<domainContainer::Domain*> >, unsigned int, int)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/movetypes.cpp:508: undefined reference to `topConstraintPoints::Constraintpoints::add_active_endpoint(domainContainer::Domain*, utility::VectorThree, int)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: ../../build/movetypes.o: in function `movetypes::CTRegrowthMCMovetype::select_noncontig_segs(std::vector<domainContainer::Domain*, std::allocator<domainContainer::Domain*> >&, std::vector<std::vector<domainContainer::Domain*, std::allocator<domainContainer::Domain*> >, std::allocator<std::vector<domainContainer::Domain*, std::allocator<domainContainer::Domain*> > > >&, std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<domainContainer::Domain*, std::allocator<domainContainer::Domain*> >, std::allocator<std::vector<domainContainer::Domain*, std::allocator<domainContainer::Domain*> > > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::vector<domainContainer::Domain*, std::allocator<domainContainer::Domain*> >, std::allocator<std::vector<domainContainer::Domain*, std::allocator<domainContainer::Domain*> > > > > >&, std::vector<domainContainer::Domain*, std::allocator<domainContainer::Domain*> >&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)':
/home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/movetypes.cpp:624: undefined reference to `topConstraintPoints::Constraintpoints::add_active_endpoint(domainContainer::Domain*, utility::VectorThree, int)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/movetypes.cpp:631: undefined reference to `topConstraintPoints::Constraintpoints::add_growthpoint(domainContainer::Domain*, domainContainer::Domain*)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/movetypes.cpp:632: undefined reference to `topConstraintPoints::Constraintpoints::add_stem_seg_pair(domainContainer::Domain*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/jakub/LatticeDNAOrigami/src/movetypes.cpp:645: undefined reference to `topConstraintPoints::Constraintpoints::add_active_endpoint(domainContainer::Domain*, utility::VectorThree, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'calc_num_walks' failed
make: *** [calc_num_walks] Error 1
```

Now I have tried many solutions posted online, but none of them was successful. I have read about the different version of GCC used for the different objects I create, although I believe I use the same versions for everything.

Comment: Do you have all the same libraries installed as well? These are compiler errors. You either don't have the needed libraries, or this code needs fixing so it can compile. If you only installed a compiler, that's not enough.

Comment: ... in particular, the issues seem largely, perhaps entirely, with a C++ library providing class `potential::OrigamiPotential`.  Apparently, the library's headers were found, but not the binary library.  That's an odd, but not impossible situation.  Are you perhaps building things out of order?

Comment: Have you build code in `$(BUILD)` yourself? Are these all the objects in there? Part of the errors are there because you are missing `-lboost_system` in LDFLAGS.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I have build the code in `$(BUILD)` myself. There are also some extra objects that are not necessary for this build.

Comment: @sweenish all the libraries should be installed

Comment: @JohnBollinger As I understand it, all the .o files are already built and I have them stored in `$(BUILD)$`. To completely fill the picture, all the objects were already used to build another program that worked just fine and that's the reason why they are not build in this makefile, as they are already built.

Comment: OK you build some objects by some unknown means (not by the makefile shown), you link some but perhaps not all of them together, and now you have undefined references. I'm afraid you are not providing enough information for anyone to help you.

Comment: You need to figure out which one of those object files in `$(BUILD)` defines the symbols that are missing (`potential::OrigamiPotential::...`) and add that object file to your link line.  It's pretty simple... if you don't want to have to figure it out you can just add them all.  It will make your program larger but extra unused objects won't break anything.